# Is there a way for me to conditionally link multiple indices in a query?

Tags: elasticsearch

Within my cluster I have two indices, one containing employee information and group memberships and another containing group information such as id, names, proxy_id etc. These will be referred to as the employee index and the group index respectively.

I would like to construct a query which will only return documents to users provided they are a part of the correct group. The unfortunate part is that documents will only have one of several proxy_ids attached to them. In order to return the correct document my query will need to check the user index and verify that their group memberships are appropriate by checking each group they are apart of and checking each proxy address against the current document.

I understand that this needs to fall inside a 'must' condition however I am unsure how to structure this or if it is indeed possible.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is for an Elastic Search Cluster running Elastic 6.6

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient way of doing Joins in elasticsearch, you could however add the information you need to the user documents. 
You should try to [denormalize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/denormalization.html) your data as much as possible. Try to store all the information you need in one document - dont care about duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple indices .. say in the node js.. something like this

```
elasticClient.search({
                         index: 'pubmed-index,biorxiv-index',
                          type: 'pubmed-paper,biorxiv-paper',
                         "size": 10,
                          body: {
                            "query": {
                              "bool": {
                                  "must": [

                                      {
                                          "query_string": {
                                              "query": `${searchKeyword}`,
                                              "default_operator": "AND",
                                              "fields":[]
                                          }
                                      },
                                      {
                                          "query_string": {
                                              "query": `${pubType[0]}`,

                                              "fields": [
                                                  "Publication Type"
                                              ]
                                          }
                                      },
                                       {
                                          "query_string": {
                                              "query": `${searchJournal}`,

                                              "fields": [
                                                  "Journal"
                                              ]
                                          }
                                      }

                                  ]
                                  ,
                                  "filter": [

                                      {

                                          "range": {
                                              "Date Revised": {
                                                  "gte":`${searchGreaterYear}`,
                                                  "lte": `${searchLesserYear}`,
                                                  "format": "yyyy"
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  ]
                              }
                          }
                      }
                        }).then(function (resp) {
                            console.log(searchPublicationType[0],searchLesserYear,searchGreaterYear,searchKeyword);
                            // return res.json(resp)
                        return res.json({source:resp.hits.hits,total:resp.hits})
                         // return res.json('Hi')
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log(err.message);
                            return res.json(err.message)
                        })
```